# (rails) postgres error (column "posts.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

Welcome.....

I want to get the most user post on my rails app

```
@section.posts.select("posts.*, count(posts.user_id) as user_posts_count").group('posts.user_id')
.order("user_posts_count DESC").limit(10)
```

But I have issue with postgreSQL while my code work without any issue on sqlit3 and mysql2

> PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "posts.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
>   LINE 1: SELECT  posts.*, count(posts.user_id) as user_posts_count FR...

I need to use postgreSQL because it is the best for heroku 
but i don't know why I get this error on PostgreSQL

I hope if anyone help me >>>

Comment: Never use `select *` with `group by`.

Comment: That error is telling you exactly what is wrong. Every column in your `select()` must also be in your `group()`. Excluding of course calculations like `count()`, `sum()`, `avg()`, etc. You probably only want to select something like user_id. `@section.posts.select("user_id, count(user_id) as user_posts_count").group(:user_id).order("user_posts_count DESC").limit(10)`.

Comment: thank you brother its work now ,I think I still need more experience thank you again , but why is work with mysql and sqlite while doesn't work on postgreSQL

Answer (score 1):

remove the id from the group, you should add all others fields in group by, using .* is a bad pratice, pls don't use .* in select that have for example, a count()